# How to pass array of value to api call and store response in single array using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, object

I have array of values, will pass each array value to api call and
I need to know how to save all response in single array in angular

```
this.result:[]=[];
this.formData=["S1", "S2"]

ngOnInit() {
 for(let item of formData) {
  this.httpClient.post(this.PartsAPIURL, item, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
       this.result.push(...data);
    });
  }
}

console.log(result);


Expected Result;

Response all should be stored in single array.
```

Answer (score 1):

`forkJoin` will make multiple requests and emit a single array of all responses:

```
public result: [] = [];
public formData = ['S1', 'S2'];

private requests = this.formData.map(
    item => this.httpClient.post(this.PartsAPIURL, item, { headers })
);

private results$ = forkJoin(this.requests);

ngOnInit() {
    this.results$.subscribe(
        result => this.result = result
    );
}
```